# backup database error in SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have problem to backup my database, the error:

> Backup failed for Server 'SERV1'.  (Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended)
>
> ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlError: Cannot open backup device
>   'D:\Backup\POSDW\POSDW_backup_2016_10_27_000002_9498971.bak'.
>   Operating system error 5(Access is denied.). (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)

Comment: Is this a SQL Server on your own, local machine, or a remote one? The backup will be stored **on the drives of the SQL Server machine** - not your local machine - just to keep that in mind if you're trying to back up a LAN-based server machine ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According the error message:

```
error 5(Access is denied.)
```

You or the user account of the sql service, has no access to the backup device:

```
D:\Backup\
```

Comment: can you tell me how to fix it ?

Comment: well, allow read/write for the account or change the user. for a quick test allow access to everyone to d:\Bacup